# Convert a git pre-commit hook to a git pre-receive hook

Tags: python, git, githooks

I want to write a git pre-receive hook that will check for PEP-8 code compliance on all new .py files.

There are already some git *pre-commit* hooks [that do exactly that](https://github.com/cbrueffer/pep8-git-hook/blob/master/pre-commit)-- but I need a *pre-receive* hook.

If I just use the given pre-commit hooks as is, I get errors like: `remote: fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`. My explanation for this error is that the hook is looking for committed python files, since it was written as a pre-commit hook. But since we're using it as a server-side pre-receive hook, it's looking in the wrong place for those .py files.

How can I make use of the already existing pre-commit hooks and use them on the server-side as pre-receive hooks?

Comment: The hook is looking for the actual files in the working tree - that is, in the project folder. Your remote repository is most probably a bare repository, having no files in working tree and only `.git/` folder. Data, transferred from one repo to another has no python files too - it's just Git internal binary files. So there's nothing to check.

Comment: Yes, I gathered that. What can I do about it? How can I access the *.py files from the remote repo?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is a post-receive hook to: 1) `git checkout HEAD`; 2) run code check; 3) if it fails - `git reset --hard HEAD^`; But that's probably not good.